# Android Jetpack Compose Lazy column items with index?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

How to access the current item's index of LazyColumn in Jetpack Compose.

```
LazyColumn {
  items(viewModel.list) { item ->
      // Here I want to get the index of the item
      Timber.d("item - $item")
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `itemsIndexed(itemsList) { index, item ->`  instead of `items`

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can use the `itemsIndexed()` extension function which provides the `index`.

```
LazyColumn() {
    itemsIndexed(viewModel.list) { index, item ->
        //..
    }
}
```